Fitting 2D points into a non-overlapping square grid
Imagine you have a bunch of real-number 2D coordinates. How would you organize those points into a square grid, without any two points overlapping onto the same square, while trying to keep each item as close to its original position as possible?
For example see here, which does this for different parameters of products.

Can you [edit] your question to explain the problem statement more clearly?  It's not clear to me what it means to "organize [..] points into a square grid".  Please specify the problem more precisely.  What are the inputs to the algorithm, what is the desired output, and how are the two required to relate to each other?  What objective function are you trying to minimize?  How do you aggregate all the distances for the different points into a single objective function?  An example picture is not a substitute for a general problem specification.
